# Can GCC issue a warning when 0 is passed as an argument?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I have been told that you could add some special instruction to your code to make GCC issue a warning when it detects that 0 is being passed as an argument (which means, when it is possible at compile-time).

I have looked for it but haven’t been able to find it. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) you can use to warn on null pointers:

```
void foo(void *data) __attribute__((nonnull));

int main(void)
{
    foo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -c t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:5: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
```

I'm not aware of anything built-in to check for 0 for integer types though.

You might find something that suits your need in the various `BUILD_BUG_*` macros from the Linux kernel though. They're in `include/linux/kernel.h`. ([Cross-referenced here](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L669).)